# How can I eliminate this error using the websocket library?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I cobbled together the following code from an example in https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#python-lt-36  This would no doubt be simpler in Python 3.6+, but unfortunately the distro I am using (Raspbian) hosts Python 3.5.3.  Clearly, I have done something wrong, but I don't know what.  What did I do wrong, and is there a simpler approach?

```
def my_callback1(channel):  # Down Arrow Pressed
    Return, Cursor = update.upArrow()
    if Return:
        message = "Control, " + str(Cursor)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))

@asyncio.coroutine
def SendMessage(message):
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000')
    try:
        yield from websocket.send(message)
    finally:
        yield from websocket.close()

GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[0], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback1, bouncetime=bTime)  # Down Arrow
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sbin/button.py", line 25, in my_callback1
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 671, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 583, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.
```

Comment: Looks like your platform's event loop policy does not automatically create event loops outside the main thread. Try `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop(); asyncio.set_event_loop(loop); loop.run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))` instead of `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))` in `my_callback1`

Comment: That does it!  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935153/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-dummy-1)

Comment: No, this is a little different.  The linked question was a case of not using an await statement. This is a case of  not automaticaly creating loops outside the main thread.  The solution above works.

Comment: Ahem, no :) Have a look at the traceback in the linked question and the first comment below it. The issue was the same as in your case; the need to explicitly create an event loop and set it in the current context when operating outside the main thread. The missing `await` mentioned in the answer's comment was a result of the switch made from `time.sleep` to `asyncio.sleep`; the second, unrelated recommendation made in user4815162342's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full solution, thanks to shmee:

```
def my_callback1(channel):  # Down Arrow Pressed
    Return, Cursor = update.downArrow()
    if Return:
        message = "Control, " + str(Cursor)
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))
@asyncio.coroutine
def SendMessage(message):
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000')
    try:
        yield from websocket.send(message)
    finally:
        yield from websocket.close()

GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[0], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback1, bouncetime=bTime)  # Down Arrow
```